# Why does RGoogleDocs need to allocate a vector of 3.2Gb to run?

Tags: r, out-of-memory, google-docs

I recently installed RGoogleDocs from github:

```
> devtools::install_github("duncantl/RGoogleDocs")
```

The package compiled and installed successfully, apart from the last line of output:

```
...
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RGoogleDocs)
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Reloading installed RGoogleDocs
Error : cannot allocate vector of size 3.2 Gb
```

Whenever I try to use the library, I get that same error:

```
> library(RGoogleDocs)
Error : cannot allocate vector of size 3.2 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RGoogleDocs’
```

3.2 Gb seems an awful lot of RAM. Is there some mistake I am making or is this just a very memory-hungry package? I only have 2 Gb available in this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the R session fixed this issue.